# If $~a^3 + b^3 = c^3~$ has nonzero integer solutions and $~c-b~$ is a cubic number and $~c-b \neq 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $~a^3 + b^3 = c^3~$ has nonzero integer solutions, because:

$c^3 - b ^ 3 = (c - b)((c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb) = a ^ 3,\quad (1)$

if $~c-b~$ is a cubic number and $~c-b \neq 1~$, divide both side of $~(1)~$ by $~c - b~$ get

$(c - b) ^ 2 + 3cb = x^3.\quad (2)$

It seems $~3 \mid \ x~$ and  $~3 \mid \ c~$ or $~b,~$ how to prove this?

Edit: add tag number-theory

Comment: Not my area, but i have never seen a proof for this other than the Eisenstein integers. My expectation is that there is nothing elementary and short that can be done to prove this, although it is quite true. Here "it" means Fermat's Last Theorem for exponent $3$

Comment: Not really that related but the case for exponent $4$ can be proved in a pretty elementary manner using Fermat's method of descent. Anyway though, from what I know about Will Jagy if he says there probably isn't an elementary proof then I wouldn't hold out too much hope on finding one.

Comment: @WillJagy Let $~(c-b)^2=y^3,~$ from $~(2)~$ we can get:
$~x^3-y^3=(x-y)((x-y)^{2}+3xy)=3cb$.

Comment: What do you mean, "it seems $3\mid x$"? You can't mean, in all numerical examples you've tried, $3\mid x$, because there are no numerical examples of nonzero integer solutions of $a^3+b^3=c^3$.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I write here. This hypothesis is probably not true. Here is a counterexample: $ c=155, b=31, x=31. $

Added

$ (c-b)=y^3  \wedge (c-b)^2 +3ab=x^3  \Rightarrow  a^3 +b^3=c^3  (a=xy).$ 
Such numbers c, b, x, are known don't exist. What is the point to prove their divisibility properties.

Comment: $155-31=124,~124~$ isn't a cubic number.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $~(c−b)^2=y^3,~$ from  $~(2)~$ get:

$x^3−y^3=(x−y)((x−y)^2+3xy)=3cb,\quad (3) $

if $~x-y \neq 3,c,b~$ suppose $~(x-y) \mid c,~$ divide both side of  $(3)\ $ by $~3$:

$(x−y)^2+3xy=3c_1b,\quad (4) $

form $~(4)~$ we see $~3 \mid (x−y)^2,~$ because  $~(x-y) \neq 3,~$then  $~3 \mid c_1,~$

form $~(4)~$ get $~3^2k^2+3xy=9c_2b,\quad (5) $

divide both side of  $(5)\ $ by $~3$:

$~3k^2+xy=3c_2b,\quad (6) $

form $~(6)~$ we see $~3 \mid x~$ or $~y,~$ if $~3 \mid x,~$ problem solved, if $~3 \mid y,~$ form $~(2)~$ we see $~3 \mid x.$

I dont know is the proof above right and the cases when $~(x-y)=3~$or $~c~$ or $~b.$

Comment: How do you get from (4) and $3\mid(x-y)^2$ to $3\mid c_1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Because if $~3 \mid (x-y)^2~$ then $~3 \mid (x-y)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Thanks, yes, there's problem.